Why was my passport returned without my UK visa and no refusal letter?
I applied for a UK visa but with all required documents, but unfortunately my passport was returned without a visa and no refusal letter. What could have caused it?

Have you asked the embassy?

yes send the mail to embassy ...

Maybe the refusal letter is sent separately

This question is related.

no letter sent separately...

How recently was the passport sent/returned? Based on a recent renewal of UK passport, it might be possible that they've returned the passport/supporting documents as soon as they've been recorded on their system (so you have them back as soon as possible), while the application is being considered (but visa applications may not work that way).

is it any chance to get visa in this situation
